# Pushed View controller is not found in the navigation stack?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i am pushing a testviewcontroller from a viewcontroller.testviewcontroller has a back button and a yes button.when pressing the back button i am going back to the previous by using

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

when pressing the Yes button i am pushing another view controller using

```
 GettingViewController *get  =[[GettingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GettingViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:get animated:NO];
```

this are all working fine.in the rewardsget when pressing a button i am poping back to testviewcontroller.using this `

```
for (TestViewController*vc in [self.navigationController viewControllers]) {
            if ([vc isKindOfClass: [TestViewController class]]){

                 [[self navigationController] popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
            }
        }
`
```

but when i am pressing the back button in that view it needs to go to my new pushed view controller ie rewardsget.But when i am printing the view controllers it is not present in the stack.so it is again going back to the first pushed viewcontroller,not the latest.can anybody help me on this?

Comment: try adding NSLog inside your loop, is your loop executed?

Comment: ya its working.that is not the problem.when i am printing the viewcontrollers in the back button it is not printing rewardsget.that i have been already pushed.thats the problem.

Comment: @bugfinder I think you took the local variable; so it is released when it went out of function/method; So try to provide property synthesize and check it once;

Comment: What if you write `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in your rewardsget's button click ?

Comment: @Maulik it is going back to the viewcontroller from which i first pushed the test.but not to rewardsget.that i pushed from test.

Comment: @bugfinder: I assume your stack as viewcontroller->testviewcontroller-> rewardsget . Right ?

Comment: @Maulik   yes exactly,i was not getting the rewardsgt in the stack

Comment: @bugfinder: what did u mean by but when i am pressing the back button in that view it needs to go to my new pushed view controller ie rewardsget. new pushed VC ? or previous VC ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15406/discussion-between-maulik-and-bugfinder)

Comment: @Maulik last i pushed rewrdsget.i want to go back to that.that i meant?

Comment: @bugfinder: last you pushed rewrdsget so currently you are in rewrdsget Right ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have multiple instances of TestViewController in your stack. To get to the correct one just pass a pointer to TestViewController to your GettingViewController, you may want to have a property:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) TestViewController* testViewController;`

When you're ready to go back to your TestViewController call `[self.navigationController popToViewController: self.testViewController animated: YES];`.

That said, it sounds like your navigation flow may need some more thought. On iOS a hub-and-spoke navigation flow is the most natural.

Answer (score 0):

in your for loop you go through all the viewControllers but already pretend that these are TestViewController (TestViewController*vc ...). Of course the first one you are looking for isKindOfClass TestViewController then!

Try changing this to UIViewController*vc!